# ProcessPoolExecuter with inheretence memory on windows

Tags: python, concurrency, fork, process-pool

I want to use ProcessPoolExecuter to decode messages I get from a generator.
before initializing the ProcessPoolExecuter I initialize a dictionary needed for the decoding.
I want my child processes to copy this dictionary so they can use it to decode the message.
since I'm using windows, it uses spawn to create the new process and so it does not inherent the dictionary.

I tried to run get_all_start_methods to see if I can change the mp_context to fork but it seems it's unavailable.

Is there a known way to use processes on windows which inherent the parent process memory?

Comment: Check [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Also take a look on [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html).

Comment: You could try to use the "initializer" in the constructor of "ProcessPoolExecutor" to transfer the dictionary (if pickleable) once when the process is created.

Comment: Take a look at the Manager class